# Tektro RL 340 brake levers cannot find tightening bolt to keep shifter secure

Tags: road-bike

I have this [bike](https://www.decathlon.co.uk/triban-rc100-road-bike-grey-id_8377732.html) from Decathlon, but the right shifter started to come loose and drop down, so I have unwound the bar tape and proceeded to move it back up.

But unlike my old shifters there is no bolt to tighten it up! I have looked everywhere on it, but cannot see it, it seems that is only held in securely by the bar tape. Is there a way to make this more secure? As at the moment it is still moving around.

It has Tektro RL 340 brake levers, not sure if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brake levers are held in place by a metal band that wraps around the bars. The band is tightened with a bolt inside the brake lever. One may see the head of the bolt when pulling the brake lever and looking into the gap between hoods and lever.

A L-shaped hex key should easily reach it. The brake cable might be in the way though. By slackening or usinga ball-head hex key one may adjust that bolt without removing the brake cable.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the information on the docs https://www.tektro.com/upload/Product/F_20150915101997SS8z8t.PDF. Now I need to find a longer allen key to get down it!